# callback method for soft keyboard changes?

Tags: android, callback, keyboard

Is there any callback methods for soft keyboard up and down. I want to do some action when soft keyboard is up and down. I know to check whether the keyboard is up or down. But that i should call that method from somewhere. Here I don't want to call it. It should be triggered automatically when there is change in soft keyboard state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it is worked in my project

`R.id.activityRoot` is  ParentLayout ID

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
            activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {

                            try {
                                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                                        .getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels,
                                                        // its probably a
                                                        // keyboard...
                                //do your stuff here keyboard shown
                                }else {     //do your stuff here keyboard not visible }

                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: this is for checking whether the keyboard is up or down rt?not a callback method na?

Comment: After adding this code when i tap on the textviews or buttons in the layout.keyboard disappears :( how to prevent it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67000/discussion-between-seethalakshmi-and-jenuine).